# Refreshing Fragment everytime navigational drawer item is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have BaseActivity with navigational drawer where am using fragment manager to show/hide the fragments in fragment layout, when each navigational drawer item is clicked, i want to refresh my fragment every time navigational item is clicked i tried couple of things like fragment attach/detach but it is not working, Can anyone please help me on how to refresh my fragment every time navigational item is clicked.

Comment: did you try `view.invalidate();`?

Comment: what content is to be refreshed?

Comment: You can try replace fragment ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can broadcast an update action from this nav drawer callback:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE); // Just string constant
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
        return false;
}
```

And then register receiver in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter(Consts.ACTION_KEYPAD_DISARMED));
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Write here code of fragment updating
    }
};
```